# Auto Click on UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an app which displays a UIAlertView with two choices "Install" and "Cancel"
Currently testers manually click on "Install" button to initiate the install.

What i would like to do is to automate this process... Is there a way i can get the handle /reference to this UIAlertView and automate the clicking of the "Install" button?

PS: The scenario is this. I use TestFlightApp(testflightapp.com) , Now my code clicks on the URL provided by TestFlightApp to install this build , however when i click the link an alertview (possibly displayed by safari) comes up. I want to get handle of this or to dismiss it

Comment: How is it even possible that a different app displays an alert within your app? Do you perhaps mean some library/framework that you included? If so, it might help to know what exactly you're talking about, perhaps there's a less hacky way than messing with the alert view.

Comment: Possible that you're developing a MobileSubstrate extension?

Comment: Why? Is it too much to ask your testers to tap "install"?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. That UIAlertView is displayed from a MobileSafari page (albeit in a web clip) and you have no control over the UIAlertView or its delegates.

This is intentional, the user should be the only one able to confirm something as significant as an app install.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an app which displays a UIAlertView with two choices "Install" and "Cancel" Currently testers manually click on "Install" button to initiate the install. What i would like to do is to automate this process.
>
> The UIAlertView is displayed by a different app

These two are contradictionary. However, if it *really* is your app that displays the alert view:

#### Part one:

If you got the handle, you can use this message to dismiss it:

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

#### Part two: how to get the first UIAlertView object in your window

```
- (UIAlertView *) recuresiveSearchAlertViewInView:(UIView *)mainView
{
    if ([mainView isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
        return (UIAlertView *)mainView;
    UIView *found = nil;
    for (UIView *view in mainView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
        {
            found = view;
            break;
        }
        if (!found)
            found = [self recursiveSearchAlertViewInView:view];
    }
    return found;
}
```

then call:

```
UIAlertView *av = [self recursiveSearchAlertViewInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the details..The scenario is this. I use TestFlightApp(https://testflightapp.com) , Now my code clicks on the URL provided by TestFlightApp to install this build , however when i click the link an alertview (possibly displayed by safari) comes up. I want to get handle of this or to dismiss it .